# Really slow queries on Mysql + Percona

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, database-administration

Hello I've been asked to audit a database from a joomla site. There's almost 250 tables in the most important one and another couples databases, working at the same time, but the main problem here is the slow queries.

In the slow query log we can see things like this:

```
# User@Host: user @ localhost []  Id: 186330
# Schema: mainDB  Last_errno: 1160  Killed: 0
# Query_time: 92.095105  Lock_time: 0.232432  Rows_sent: 0
Rows_examined: 0  Rows_affected: 0
# Bytes_sent: 0
SET timestamp=1463917461;
SELECT *
FROM `tablename`
WHERE NOT(`option` LIKE'com_%');
```

This is the create query of that table:

```
 CREATE TABLE tablename (
   id bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   option varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   option2 varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   option3 varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
 ALTER TABLE tablename
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

This is the spec of the server:

```
2 x 3ghz CPU cores, CentOS, 5 Gb Ram, 50 Gb SSD
Mysql 5.6
Server version: 5.6.29-76.2-log Percona Server (GPL), Release 76.2...
```

Any idea why the slow queries?

Answer (score 0):

```
EXPLAIN SELECT *
    FROM `tablename`
    WHERE NOT(`option` LIKE'com_%');
```

You will probably find it saying "ALL".  That means that the query must simply scan the entire table.

How big is the table?

"Rows_sent: 0 Rows_examined: 0" is puzzling -- are there really no rows in the resultset?  That is, does every `option` start with 'com_'?  Do they really need to run that query?

I don't see a way to optimize the query.  I don't think `INDEX(option)` will help, but you could try.

Comment: There's like 100k records on that table but I'm still getting Rows_sent: 0
Rows_examined: 0  Rows_affected: 0. No all start with 'com_'. Do you think this might be a problem with the server??

Comment: What is the output from that `EXPLAIN`?